# Spring Boot, FreeMarker и кодировка Windows-1252

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, freemarker

Приложение на Spring Boot, MVC и FreeMarker. Везде, где только можно, выставил кодировку UTF-8 - и в заголовке ftl, и в pom.xml, и сделал бин viewResolver - результат не меняется, получаю "?" вместо русских букв. С БД все нормально - оттуда получаю русские символы.
Вот несколько частей моего конфига:

```html
<#ftl encoding='UTF-8'>
<#macro page>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
              content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" charset="UTF-8"/>
```

Здесь настройка maven:

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <jvmArguments>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Здесь viewResolver и его инжект:

```java
@Bean
public FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver() {
    FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    viewResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

```java
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.freeMarker();
    registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
}
```

Результат один - я получаю страницу в кодировке Windows-1252. Операционная система - Mac OS.

В чем еще может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще добавить кодировку для `MessageConverters` в настройках [`WebMvcConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.forEach(converter -> {
            if (converter instanceof AbstractHttpMessageConverter) {
                ((AbstractHttpMessageConverter) converter)
                        .setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                if (converter instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter) {
                    ((StringHttpMessageConverter) converter)
                            .setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
                }
            } else if (converter instanceof FormHttpMessageConverter) {
                ((FormHttpMessageConverter) converter)
                        .setCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                ((FormHttpMessageConverter) converter)
                        .setMultipartCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: увы, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

В настройках `maven` нужно добавить кодировку и в плагинах к нему:

```xml
<properties>
    <project.java.version>1.8</project.java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${project.java.version}</source>
                <target>${project.java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

См. [How to configure encoding in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3017695/11141611)